# DevExpress: Gridview Image; How to resize image to fit the size of the cell

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, devexpress

I have a GridView that I am populating with test data. The test model includes a System.Drawing.Image field that I am using to display a auto generated bitmap image for that particular row.

The image is currently being loaded into the Grid View. How can I set the Image to stretch to the current width of the cell? I do not want to use the custom draw cell event because it will force the image to be recreated every time the grid changes (all events regarding the grid).

Here is my test code of how I populate the grid:

```
        Random random = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        {
            Image image = Image.FromFile(@"MyPicture.bmp");
            IArrivalModel arrivalModel = new ArrivalModel()
            {
                SupplierCode = $"{i}",
                SupplierShortName = $"Supplier {i}",
                DeliveredQuantity = random.Next(5000, 8000),
                InStockQuantity = random.Next(0, 5000),
                ExpectedUsageQuantity = random.Next(0, 3000),
                InventoryItemShortName = $"Inventory Item {i}",
                InventoryItemCode = $"{i}",
                RegistrationNumber = $"{(char)random.Next('A', 'Z')}{(char)random.Next('A', 'Z')} {random.Next(0, 9)}{random.Next(0, 9)} GP",
                ButtonRegion = image
        };

            arrivalModels.Add(arrivalModel);
        }

        gridControl1.DataSource = arrivalModels;
```

And the Arrival Model:

```
public class ArrivalModel : IArrivalModel
{
    public string SupplierCode { get; set; }
    public string SupplierShortName { get; set; }
    public string RegistrationNumber { get; set; }
    public string InventoryItemCode { get; set; }
    public string InventoryItemShortName { get; set; }
    public decimal DeliveredQuantity { get; set; }
    public decimal InStockQuantity { get; set; }
    public decimal ExpectedUsageQuantity { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// A place holder to display the image in
    /// </summary>
    public Image ButtonRegion { get; set; }
}
```

I have tried DevExpress' example on how to do this, but was unable to get the Image to appear

```
RepositoryItemTextEdit textEdit = new RepositoryItemTextEdit();
textEdit.ContextImageOptions.Image = Image.FromFile(@"MyImage.bmp");
gridView1.Columns[nameof(ArrivalModel.ButtonRegion)].UnboundType = 
DevExpress.Data.UnboundColumnType.Object;
gridView1.Columns[nameof(ArrivalModel.ButtonRegion)].ColumnEdit = textEdit;
gridControl1.RepositoryItems.Add(textEdit);
```

Comment: Have you tried using a RepositoryItemPictureEdit to display the image? It had stretch/zoom/clip properties to dictate how the image should be sized.

Comment: @Brendon, I have tried using a RepositoryItemPictureEdit, but every time the CustomRowCellEdit events get called, the Size Mode changes back to squeezed.

Comment: What's inside CustomRowCellEdit event?

Comment: How was RepositoryItemPictureEdit set?